# reference console_loglevel ERROR in kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a Linux module, which has a debug function and I just want to call that function in debug mode.
Now I have code like this:

```
if (console_loglevel >= CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_DEBUG)
    dump_my_message(dev, my_msg);
```

But when build this code in linux-next, it will throw below error:

```
CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#2)
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 2738 modules
ERROR: "console_printk" [drivers/mymodule.ko] undefined!
scripts/Makefile.modpost:91: recipe for target '__modpost' failed
make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 1
Makefile:1117: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Can you help to find out how to make this work? thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation error is caused by the fact that `console_printk` symbol is not exported so it cannot be used by modules.

What you really should use, however, is [Dynamic debug](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/dynamic-debug-howto.txt) functionality and its `pr_debug()`/`dev_dbg()` functions.

Basically what you need is to ensure that `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG` is enabled in your kernel, use `dev_dbg()` in all places where you want to write some debugging code and then dynamically enable your debug messages, for example:

1. To enable all the messages in your module, add `dyndbg=+p` at the end of your `insmod`/`modprobe` call.
2. To selectively enable only some of the messages, use query language described in the documentation. For example, to only enable messages from functions `foo()` and `bar()` in your module, use:

   ```
   insmod mymodule.ko dyndbg="func foo +p; func bar +p"
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I saw console_loglevel is also used by driver/nubus/nubus.c. How does this module use the console_loglevel /console_printk if it not exported? How do I export the module of console_printk  from printk? Thanks!

Comment: nubus is not a kernel module, it's compiled into the main kernel image. That's why it has no problem accessing those symbols - this restriction only concerns code written as kernel modules. You can modify your kernel and export any symbol, just look for EXPORT_SYMBOL() macro. Keep in mind, however, that if you will use any symbol that you exported yourself in the kernel, this module will only be able to work with your kernel.